# Cloud SQL (postgres) foreign data wrapper connection time out to replica instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, foreign-data-wrapper

Hey we have some issues using `postgres_fdw` extension in **CloudSQL when connecting to a replica instance**. We forwarded the problem to the GCP support but their answer was not really related to our problem. Thus, we have another try here:

## Problem

we are using the `postgres_fdw` extension in our application in order to be able to run joins across databases.

We have 2 databases on the master instance (which has a replica instance)

- **analytics**
- **animal** (the name has historically reasons :D)

and used to have a foreign data wrapper connection from **analytics -> animal**.

This works fine using the IP address of the CloudSQL **master** instance as describe in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions?#postgres_fdw).

The foreign data wrapper settings get synced to the replica instance and therefore still point to the master instance (-> still using the master instance's IP).

A "diagram" would look like this:

> master --`postgres_fdw(IP address A)`--> master (IP address A)

> **replica** --`postgres_fdw(IP address A)`--> master (IP address A)

In order to avoid that we hit the master instance when querying the replica, we wanted to change the setup to:

> master --`postgres_fdw(IP address B)`--> replica (IP address B)

> **replica** --`postgres_fdw(IP address B)`--> replica (IP address B)

We wanted to change this so that our foreign data wrapper always points to the replica instance (also on master - which is fine) by changing the IP address when setting it up.

**However, connecting to the replica via its IP and the foreign data wrapper is not working. We always get a connection timeout when importing the schema (on master)**

### Setup script which we run on the master

```
BEGIN;

    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;

    --- Update foreign data server
    DROP SERVER IF EXISTS "animal_fdw" CASCADE;
    CREATE SERVER "animal_fdw" FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host '$FDW_HOST', dbname '$TARGET_DB_NAME');

    --- Create user mapping for default agrando user and metabase
    CREATE USER MAPPING FOR "$USER" SERVER "animal_fdw" OPTIONS(user '$USER', password '$PASSWORD');

    --- Update Schema
    DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS "$SCHEMA_NAME";
    CREATE SCHEMA "$SCHEMA_NAME";

    --- The following line times out
    IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public from SERVER "animal_fdw" into "$SCHEMA_NAME"
COMMIT;
```

- works when `$FDW_HOST=<IP_Address_A>` (master)
- `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public from SERVER "animal_fdw" into "$SCHEMA_NAME"` times out when `$FDW_HOST=<IP_Address_B>` (replica)

### Logs

```
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:56:24 GMT
DROP SERVER
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:56:24 GMT
CREATE SERVER
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:56:24 GMT
CREATE USER MAPPING
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:56:24 GMT
CREATE USER MAPPING
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:56:24 GMT
CREATE USER MAPPING
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:56:24 GMT
DROP SCHEMA
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:58:36 GMT
CREATE SCHEMA
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:58:36 GMT
ERROR:  could not connect to server "animal_fdw"
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:58:36 GMT
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:58:36 GMT
    Is the server running on host "<IP Address B>" and accepting
Thu, 10 Sep 2020 14:58:36 GMT
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

We already tried it on all our environments to make sure that the environment has no influence We also made sure that we did not have a typo in the IP address

Comment: did you find solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey Yogi, unfortunately we did not find a solution yet. We currently live with the problem that our replica now points the foreign data wrapper to the master instance :/

Comment: https://thedataguy.in/access-cloudsql-postgresql-fdw-from-different-vpc-or-public/

Answer (score -1):

you used a read replicas, all right? that could not be used like this way.

Comment: Your answer need to be a solution if not should comment

Comment: Thanks Rui but as mentioned in our support case I think this &quot;answer&quot; is not really related to our problem. If you read the case above closely you see that it works connecting to a normal instance from the replica (when running the schema import on the master). And we also can connect to the replica of course in a normal way. It is just timing out from within the master instance (during schema import). We DON'T ever import the schema on the replica (which I see that this would not work since it is a write operation) but we replicate the schema instead from master