# GCLOUD Postgres, using foreign data wrapper extesion results permission denied for relation

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, foreign-data-wrapper

I'm really stuck with the following problem.

At GCloud SQL I have a running postgres' instance.
That instance contains two databases. From one database (`source_db`) I want to access to another database's (`another_db`) table (`foreign_table`) using `postgres_fdw` extension. The recipe I'm employing currently is this:

1)

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
```

2. 

```
CREATE SERVER foreign_db
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (dbname 'another_db', port '5432', host '<A_PRIVATE_IP>');
```

3. 

```
CREATE USER MAPPING for guest
SERVER foreign_db
OPTIONS (user 'guest', password 's3cr3t');
```

**Update After Laurenz's answer**

The thing was here I need to use an user/role that exists on the remote server and has access to the desired remote table.

So I needed to do something like this:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING for guest
SERVER foreign_db
OPTIONS (user 'foreign_db_role', password 's3cr3t');
```

4. 

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_table
(
 // columns descripions
)
SERVER foreign_db OPTIONS (table_name 'foreign_table');

-- Alternatively I also tried with
CREATE SCHEMA external;
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public from SERVER foreign_db into external;
```

5. 

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE foreign_table TO guest;
```

The above commands runs without error, but when I tried to actually access the table I got this:

If using "external" schema

```
source_db=> select 1 from external.foreign_table limit 1;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation foreign_table
CONTEXT:  Remote SQL command: SELECT NULL FROM public.foreign_table (*)
```

If not using "external" schema

```
source_db=> select 1 from foreign_table limit 1;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation foreign_table
CONTEXT:  Remote SQL command: SELECT NULL FROM public.foreign_table
```

The only thing that smells a little is that the error message (at *) displays "public.foreign_table" instead of "external.foreign_table" even when I'm using external schema... but i don't know is that actually means something :S

As far I researched there is no way to login into the posgres instance as a superuser as that is not allowed by the Gcloud's SQL services neither a way to edit the pg_hba.conf file in order to adjust client's authentication affairs.

I searched in a lot of places but without finding what i can do to sort this out. Among the sites and pages i looked are the below list

- [The official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#postgres_fdw)
- [A personal blog's post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/21/foreign-data-wrappers-postgresql-postgres_fdw/)
- [This other SO post having a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021094/cloud-sql-postgres-foreign-data-wrapper-connection-time-out-to-replica-instanc)
- [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/288914/import-foreign-schema-fails-with-password-error-for-127-0-0-1-but-not-for-remote) and [this other post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53914/permission-denied-for-relation-table) regarding permissions and authorizations.
- [A Nice tutorial about authentication and authorization](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/authentication-and-authorization/intro-to-authn-and-authz)

P.S.

I was able to make this on a postgres' instance that i ran locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `guest` on the remote server doesn't have permissions to `SELECT` from the table. Since the query on the remote server is executed as user `guest`, you get an error.

`GRANT` the `SELECT` privilege on the table on the remote server to the user.

Comment: Thanks! you give a most valuable clue to solve this! I actually needed to GRANT SELECT but executing that statement connected to the `foreing_db` as another user that has "enought" priviligies to grant a select to `guest` on the desired table. Previously i was granting select permissions to guest on the desired table but connected into `source_db` as `guest`. So i need to connect to do same with another user in the foreign_db. That is what i needed to do, ¿right?. Do note that i actually need to run BOTH `GRANT..SELECT` statements on both databases.

Comment: That error message was owing to permissions on the remote database.

Comment: Do you know that every documentation i found, no one mention that you actually needs to connect to the foreing_db and grant permissions to the "guest" user... i even made in my local environment without the need of doing this "last step" of granting... ¿perhaps is time to report this in gcloud? i really wonder i'm not finding any document that explicity says that you need to grant select permissions to the "guest" user in both databases.

Comment: That goes without saying, you connect as user `guest` to the remote database, and if that user doesn't have permissions, it cannot `SELECT`. But thanks to your question and my answer this is clear now.

Comment: yeah.. I really hope this helps anyone else that in time found itself trapped in between of the same trouble!